# AngularJS widget inside existing Angular App

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a widget written in Angular which I am allowing users to embed into their own websites.  I have followed [this guide](http://www.mattburkedev.com/multiple-angular-versions-on-the-same-page/) to avoid conflicts when embedding into websites that already use a different version of AngularJS.

The widget is being initialised using `angular.bootstrap`

It works fine, however the widget's version of Angular is trying to initialise the parents `ng-app="parentApp"` attribute and producing the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module parentApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'parentApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to stop the widgets version of angular trying to initiate ng-app attributes?

Comment: it's not clear from the details presented in the question body what the actual issue is, and there is no code here to help us reproduce the problem you are having or present an alternative solution.  That article you linked to seems to have some good ideas on the subject;  did you miss some crucial element of it when trying to implement their ideas?

Comment: one thing I can say for certain is that *the only* way to embed an angular widget written in another version of angular into your page is if the widget is in it's own, isolated HTML element.  you cannot nest two initialized angular apps within each other.

Comment: A demo that replicates problem would also help

Comment: From the error message it is clear that you are referencing the parentApp module which is clearly not being provided, You should package the widget in a self-contained module with no reference to the parentApp module when distributing your widget to other people.